How to make Delphi mobile apps open when downloading files with a specific extension
Using Delphi 12.1 on Android and iOS.
When I download a .PGN file on my Android device, a chess app opens as it should.
How do I make my Delphi app open when a .PGN file is downloaded?

You nee to register intent filter for your application. See Android intent filter: associate app with file extension for more in-depth explanation and check FMX.Android Intents Sample for basics of how to start working with intents.
